# TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON , Axios React Express

Tags: reactjs, express, axios

I have a problem with a axios request get. Here my axios get request:

```
setInterval(()=>{ 
  
  axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/roomBefore`, {
 params: { id: '61522eca53996364cbd04348'}
}).then((res) => {
  console.log(res.data);
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log(err);
  console.log('On est dans lerreur du set');
})}
 
  , 5000);
```

Here my express route for the get request:

```
app.get('/roomBefore', function(req,res){
console.log(req.query);
const id = req.query.id;

  const Room1 = Room.findOne({_id: id});
  try{
    console.log(id);
    res.status(201).send(Room1);
  } catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
})
```

When i start the get request i have an error:

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'Topology'
    |     property 's' -> object with constructor 'Object'
    |     property 'sessionPool' -> object with constructor 'ServerSessionPool'
    --- property 'topology' closes the circle
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
```

I don't understand. Thank you for your kindness.

Comment: I guess it's telling you that `Room1` is not something that can be converted to JSON because it contains references to things that contain references to itself (circular references) which is not something the JSON specification can handle.  What you should probably do to fix it is to create a new plain object and add to that plain object just the few properties of Room1 that you actually need to send to the client.  And, make sure you don't include any of the properties that  have circular references in them.  Then, send that new object with `res.send()`.

Comment: Also, doesn't `Room.findOne()` require an `await` as in `const Room1 = await Room.findOne({_id: id})` and also the parent function needs to be `async` to allow the `await`?  Actually, this may  be the core cause of your problem as `Room1` is not currently your data, it's a database object with promise-like properties and a bunch of other stuff inside it.